# How to get date picker in asp.net

Tags: visual-studio, datetimepicker

How to get date time picker in asp.net because I'm using html format

```
<!-- invoice date -->
                            <div class="form-group left">
                                <label for="invoicedate" class="label-title"> Invoice Date : </label>
                                <input type="date" id="invoicedate" class="form-input" required="required" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I stuck beacuse don't know how to write the code behind for date. I trying to seacrh but it's using DynDateTime jQuery Plugin. I'm looking up for something simple and easy to be implement. For instance if i'm using TextBox I know how to write the code behind

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("invoiceno", TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the jQuery document ready event handler, the Bootstrap DatePicker Plugin is applied to the ASP.Net TextBox and the Date format is set to dd/MM/yyyy. Inside the Button Click event handler, the value of the Selected Date is fetched from the Request.

```
protected void datepicker_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
txtdtp. Text = datepicker. SelectedDate. ToShortDateString(); // just use this method to get dd/MM/yyyy.
datepicker. Visible = false;
}
```